# it receive the following error when use matplotlib

Tags: macos, python3, matplotlib

MathTextWarning: Font 'default' does not have a glyph for '-' [U+2212], substituting with a dummy symbol.
  MathTextWarning)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the "wrong" minus sign. Try using `U+002D, or HYPEN-MINUS` instead as this is [more commonly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) used as the minus sign for programming languages.

Comment: Thanks ! but how  to change the minus sign?